# Update table with 3 repeating values, 1 unique value, and 1 incremental value with a query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table that has 5 columns. The table looks like this:

[image]

A little explanation on the table:

1. Each `Group` has 6 properties.
2. There are around 25-30 `groups` that have the same properties. For instance, `Group 8010` has exactly the same properties as `group 8005`.
3. Only difference is, `Line` column increases by 1 for every new row.
4. I have 7 or 8 different `groups` that have 25-30 groups within them.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
I am trying to write an `insert` statement that does this:

1. Use an `Insert` statement that takes values from one `group` and inserts it into the next.
2. Use a function (I looked at `Rank()` but not sure if I can use this here) that automatically populates `Line` value based on the previous value.

My insert statement should hopefully look like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    TableName (Group, Line, Brand, Param, Value)
VALUES
    (8010 
    ,RANK()
    ,(
        Select 
            Brand, Param, Value 
        from
            TableName
        Where 
            Group = '8005'
    )
```

For the next `group` I will write the same query but change the `Group` value to `8015` and so on.

I am having difficulty figuring out the `RANK()` part and the `SELECT` subquery to get values to insert.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Edit 1:
This is what the new table would look like:
[image]

The bold section is the new data. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Does this mean `Line`s for group `8010` should be `7 - 12`?

Comment: Yup. And `line` for group `8015` should be `13-18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way in which you only have to change the `@nextGroup` variable. It uses `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
declare @table table ([Group] int, Line int, Brand char(2), [Param] varchar(64), Value varchar(256))
insert into @table values
(8005,1,'MO','CUT SPEED','55 Series'),
(8005,2,'MO','CUT BLADE','450 Series'),
(8005,3,'MO','CUT SPEED OV','60 Series'),
(8005,4,'MO','CUT BLADE OV','475 Series'),
(8005,5,'MO','CUT COMMENTS','Slow'),
(8005,6,'MO','CUT OV COMMENTS','Fast')

declare @nextGroup int = 8010
declare @currentGroup int = (select max([Group]) from @table where [Group] < @nextGroup)
declare @nextLine int = (select max([Line]) from @table where [Group] = @currentGroup)

insert into @table
    select
        @nextGroup as [Group]
        ,@nextline + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as Line
        ,t.Brand
        ,t.Param
        ,t.Value
    from @table t
    where t.[Group] = @currentGroup

set @nextGroup = 8015
set @currentGroup = (select max([Group]) from @table where [Group] < @nextGroup)
set @nextLine = (select max([Line]) from @table where [Group] = @currentGroup)

insert into @table
    select
        @nextGroup as [Group]
        ,@nextline + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as Line
        ,t.Brand
        ,t.Param
        ,t.Value
    from @table t
    where t.[Group] = @currentGroup

select * from @table
```

**USING A CURSOR**

```
--test data
declare @table table ([Group] int, Line int, Brand char(2), [Param] varchar(64), Value varchar(256))
insert into @table values
(8005,1,'MO','CUT SPEED','55 Series'),
(8005,2,'MO','CUT BLADE','450 Series'),
(8005,3,'MO','CUT SPEED OV','60 Series'),
(8005,4,'MO','CUT BLADE OV','475 Series'),
(8005,5,'MO','CUT COMMENTS','Slow'),
(8005,6,'MO','CUT OV COMMENTS','Fast')

--variables for handling data conditions
declare @nextGroup int 
declare @currentGroup int
declare @nextLine int

--table with all the group numbers to use
declare @groupTable table (nextGroup int)
insert into @groupTable values
(8010),
(8015),
(8020)

--cursor to loop through the set based inserts
declare groupCursor cursor fast_forward for
select nextGroup from @groupTable

open groupCursor
fetch next from groupCursor into @nextGroup

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    --get the last group inserted. The where condition isn't really needed
    set @currentGroup = (select max([Group]) from @table where [Group] < @nextGroup)
    --this figures out what the last line number was in the table
    set @nextLine = (select max([Line]) from @table where [Group] = @currentGroup)


    insert into @table
    select
        @nextGroup as [Group]
        --Here we increase the line number by 1 according to the last one
        ,@nextLine + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as Line
        ,t.Brand
        ,t.Param
        ,t.Value
    from @table t
    where t.[Group] = @currentGroup

    fetch next from groupCursor into @nextGroup
end

close groupCursor
deallocate groupCursor

select * from @table
```

Comment: That was PERFECT! I just don't understand how the `@nextLine` variable works. During first run, `Max(Line)` will be `6`. What is the value of `Line` in this sentence: `Line + @NextLine`? How does it go from 1 through 6?

Comment: well i'm about to change that @CrazyCucumber to make it more dynamic... give me one moment

Comment: Ok @CrazyCucumber check that out and let me know if it doesn't make sense and i'll elaborate. You can remove the cursor and manually set the parameter and it'll work the same way (correctly and accurately this time compared to the first code which only works on the first pass)

Comment: Fixed the original post so it will work now, with multiple passes. And to answer your question. It was taking 6 and adding it to 1 for the first line, adding it to 2 for the second line, etc... but this would only work for a single update. The `row_number` fixes that though.

Comment: That was beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the question @CrazyCucumber, it was an interesting problem.

Comment: Problem. After the first set of groups, I realized that the second set of groups don't necessarily follow the order. For instance: First set of groups have a `group` value of `8005, 8010, 8015, 8020`. Second set of groups, which have different values for param and value, have a `group` value of `8011, 7850, 8040, 8003`. `@currentGroup` variable will not select the right group value! :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137593/discussion-between-scsimon-and-crazy-cucumber).

Comment: is there anything else that makes these a unique pairing, like the brand or...? @CrazyCucumber

Comment: I figured it out. This is what I did:    
Changed the `@currentGroup` statement to this:    
`set @currentGroup = (select Group from TableName where LINE = (SELECT MAX(Line) from TableName))`    
This way, current group is set based on the maximum Line value. Setting it based on `Max(Group)` wouldn't work because the group values are all over the place. It is smaller than or bigger than the previous group already present.
Thank you so much. You were very helpful